# Use vue-awesome-swiper with typescript and vuejs

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, vuejs2

I have a stack about using vue-awesome-swiper with typescript in my vuejs project.
Is there any body who had this experience or maybe some example how to implements it

Problem in different loaders it cant to load template with my ts-loader

Here is my error

You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

```
| <template>
|   <div class="swiper-container">
|     <slot name="parallax-bg"></slot>
webpack: Failed to compile.
```